# Issue concerning arrays with scanf function

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having a problem with the scanf function. If i substitute a[i] with a+i it works but i don't understand why.

```
printf("Inserire i %d numeri:\n", N);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    scanf("%d", a[i]);
    scanf("%*c");
}
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    sum += a[i];

printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Comment: Where are the declarations

Comment: A+I is a pointer.  The other is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanf expects an address (pointer to a[i] ) to store the value in it. a[i] represents the value at the address a+i.

That is why you have to use &a[i] or a+i  and not a[i].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
int a[42];
```

`scanf("%d", ...)` expects the *address* of `a[i]` which `a + i` is, which is the same as `&a[i]`.

<sup>(`a[i]` in turn is equivalent to `*(a + i)` and `*&a[i]`.)</sup>

The *address* is needed as the `scanf()` needs to know *where* to write the scanned data to.

---

Seeing this

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  sum += a[i];
```

you made sure `sum` is set to `0`, before entering the loop above, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

They are different things (and the compiler likely warned you of this): `a+i` is a pointer to the element at offset `i` of the array, which is what `scanf` needs to know where to put the value read in, while `a[i]` is the *value* at that address, which is of no use to `scanf`.